# park domain automatically redirect to main domain

Tags: javascript, redirect

I parked  domain.com on domian.ir but it worked like redirection, and when you enter to domian.com that redirected to domain.ir, and I asked for my host support and they said these issues are from your script code, please tell me what codes need to change for park domain work correctly, thank you.

Comment: add your script code

Comment: unfortunately, I don`t know where is the exact place of the script code